# Cannot download ocs-url

Tags: 17.04

I was trying to download gnome theme from gnome-look.org, but when I click link, it opens url that looks like this `ocs://install?url=`.

It is supposed to open using ocs-url, but when I want to download it here https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1136805/ it tries to open in ocs-url.

How should I download it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably were trying to still click on "Install" but what you have to do is just click on the "Filename" to download the appropiate package and install it. To make it easier for you, these are the links copied from their ocs-url download page:

**ubuntu**: https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1488740853/ocs-url_3.0.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

**OpenSuse**: https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1489367751/ocs-url-3.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

**archlinux**: https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1488740879/ocs-url-3.0.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

**Fedora**: https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1488740868/ocs-url-3.0.0-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Thank you. I felt like being stucked in recursive installations.